# Out of shape and shape's color

Tags: color, pstricks, pspicture

How can I change the color of the places in the picture? Please help me.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Posting pictures of code is not acceptable.  You must post the code itself, to have any hope of getting assistance.

Answer (score 1):

For the first line use instead of `\psline[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue](8,12)...` the following macro

```
\pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue](8,12)(8,-10)(-8,-10)(-8,12)
```

or as an alternative fill the bottom margin with

```
\psframe*[linecolor=white](-8,-12)(8,-10)
```

and the right margin

```
\psframe*[linecolor=white](6,-12)(8,12)
```